# Issue with linked lib in automake and libtool

Tags: c, gcc, libxml2, automake, libtool

Hi I am developing a C libtool library. I have an issue adding dependency lib xml2. I decide to use GNU autotools, bat I am very newbie.

In configure.ac I have:

```
# Checks for libraries.
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([xmlCleanupParser],[xml xml2])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([xmlSAXVersion],[xml xml2])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([xmlSAXUserParseFile],[xml xml2])
```

In MakeFile.ac:

```
nobase_include_HEADERS =  \
    foo.h \
    bar.h \
    foo/foo.h \
    foo/bar.h 

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = \
    foo.c \
    bar.c \
        sax2.c \
    foo/foo.c \
    foo/bar.c 


check_PROGRAMS = test
test_SOURCES = test.c
test_LDADD = libfoo.la
```

The configure script output correctly:

```
checking for library containing xmlCleanupParser... -lxml2
```

In the generated Makefile there are:

```
LIBS = -lxml2 
...
libfoo.la: $(libfoo_la_OBJECTS) $(libfoo_la_DEPENDENCIES) 
$(LINK) -rpath $(libdir) $(libfoo_la_OBJECTS) $(libfoo_la_LIBADD) $(LIBS)
```

When I launch Make:

```
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -MT bar.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/bar.Tpo -c bar.c -o bar.o >/dev/null 2>&1
mv -f .deps/bar.Tpo .deps/bar.Plo
/bin/sh ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O2 -MT sax2.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/sax2.Tpo -c -o sax2.lo sax2.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I.. -g -O2 -MT sax2.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/sax2.Tpo -c sax2.c  -fno-common -DPIC -o .libs/sax2.o
sax2.c:21:29: error: libxml/encoding.h: No such file or directory
sax2.c:22:31: error: libxml/xmlversion.h: No such file or directory
sax2.c:23:27: error: libxml/parser.h: No such file or directory
sax2.c:24:30: error: libxml/xmlmemory.h: No such file or directory
sax2.c:25:25: error: libxml/SAX2.h: No such file or directory
sax2.c:26:25: error: libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory
sax2.c:27:30: error: libxml/xmlstring.h: No such file or directory
```

The make command does not link the libxml2, anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not with linking, but with compiling.  Note how it says "compile" and then complains about missing header files.  Those headers should be on your system under `/usr/include/`, so you should add `-I/usr/include` to the compilation command (whereas right now you have two -I options, for `.` and `..`).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of wasting time with `AC_SEARCH_LIBS`, you could simply use `PKG_CHECK_MODULES([libxml], [libxml-2.0])`.